# Autoloading classes from my private repository included in Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I've added my own repository to a Composer, it download properly into my another project.
Unfortunately Composer doesn't take my repository code under consideration while updating autoloading.

`autoload_namespaces.php` has many namespaces generated but any of them is my repository code. 
I could add namespaces in my `"autoloading"` section in composer.json or I could also add it in PHP using `Autoloader9287463497853476` object but those solutions (ideologically equal) doesn't interest me.

How can I force my Composer to generate autoloading for my repository code also?

Answer (score 5):

If you add your package using the repository section of composer.json, i would sugest you to include there the code for autoload, as i used here:

```
"repositories": [  
 {
      {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "brand/name",
                "type": "library",
                "version": "1.0.0",
                "dist": {
                    "url": "file:///path-to-file.zip",
                    "type": "zip",
                    "reference": "XXXX"
                },
                "autoload": {"psr-0": { "Name\\Space\\": "dest-folder" }
            },
      }            
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: so the dest-folder path is going to need to be absolute? cant use relative from the package?

Comment: As a matter of fact, you can replace file:///path-to-file.zip by ../../reldir/path-to-file.zip. According to composer docs: https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path